# How to make Spring perform real JNDI lookup if the lookup attribute is present in Resource annotation

Tags: spring, ejb, jndi, lookup

We'd like to test EJB-s in unit tests as Spring components.

The one of the EJB-s using the Resources annotation in order to look up a JNDI values like this:

```
@Resource(lookup = "java:global/myapp/portal/url")
private String portalUrl;
```

The problem is that it seems that Spring tries to look up the value by type i.e. it looks for a bean of type java.lang.String in the application context instead of using JNDI.

Here's our code.

1st context:

```
<bean id="serverMock" class="myapp.JndiServerMock">
</bean>
```

2nd context:

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="myapp">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="javax.ejb.Stateless" />
    <context:include-filter type="annotation"
        expression="javax.annotation.Resources" />
</context:component-scan>
<bean
    class="org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor">
    <property name="alwaysUseJndiLookup" value="true" />
</bean>

<bean id="clientMock" class="myapp.JndiClientMock">

<bean id="java:global/myapp/portal/url" class="java.lang.String">
    <constructor-arg value="http://localhost:8080" type="java.lang.String"/>
</bean>
```

JndiServerMock:

public class JndiServerMock {

```
public JndiServerMock() throws IllegalStateException, NamingException {
    SimpleNamingContextBuilder builder = new SimpleNamingContextBuilder();
    builder.bind("java:global/myapp/portal/url", "http://localhost:8080");
    builder.activate();
}
```

}

JndiClientMock:

public class JndiClientMock {

```
public JndiClientMock() throws NamingException {
    Hashtable<String, String> prop = new Hashtable<String, String>();
    prop.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.springframework.mock.jndi.SimpleNamingContextBuilder");
    InitialContext ic = new InitialContext(prop);
    System.err.println("result = " + ic.lookup("java:global/myapp/portal/url"));
}
```

}

ExampleBean:

@Stateless
public class ExampleBean {

```
@Resource(lookup = "java:global/myapp/portal/url")
private String portalUrl;

public ExampleBean() {
    System.err.println("portalUrl = " + portalUrl);
}
```

}

public class MainApp {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.springframework.mock.jndi.SimpleNamingContextBuilder");

    ApplicationContext applicationContext = 
        new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/spring/firstContext.xml", 
            "/spring/secondContext.xml");

    ExampleBean exampleBean = applicationContext.getBean(ExampleBean.class); 
}
```

}

If the "java:global/myapp/portal/url" bean definition is omitted then the following exception will be thrown:

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.annotation.Resource(shareable=true, lookup=java:global/myapp/portal/url, name=, description=, authenticationType=CONTAINER, type=class java.lang.Object, mappedName=)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1047)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.autowireResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:457)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.getResource(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:435)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$ResourceElement.getResourceToInject(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:559)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata$InjectedElement.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:169)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:305)
    ... 13 more

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is how you're trying to set the JNDI entry in the Spring config - [here's](https://gist.github.com/prule/5523826) an example of how to do this.  [This](http://www.javabeat.net/accessing-objects-in-jndi-using-spring/) provides examples of other ways of achieving the same thing.  However, if you're looking to do this for a unit test, I think the JUnit section [here](http://tomee.apache.org/resource-injection.html) is likely to be a neater approach, but it certainly looks like you have lots of options!